# Code to change input into capital alphanumerics

Tags: python, bots

So I have python code that works perfectly fine, it's a URL generator. When I input a `model` I want it to **automatically change the alphanumerical code to caps**. How can I do this? Please could you add the code to my existing script

```
def URLGen(model, size):
    BaseSize = 580
    #Base Size is for Shoe Size 6.5
    ShoeSize = size - 6
    ShoeSize = ShoeSize * 20
    RawSize = ShoeSize + BaseSize
    ShoeSizeCode = int(RawSize)
    URL = 'http://www.adidas.co.uk/' + str(model) + '.html?forceSelSize=' + str(model) + '_' + str(ShoeSizeCode)
    return URL

    Model = raw_input('Model #: ')
    Size = input('Size: ')

    URL = URLGen(Model, Size)

    print(URL)
```

Answer (score 3):

The upper method of strings returns a new uppercase string.

`model = model.upper()`

You should fix the indent of your function in the code sample.

Words in identifiers in python are by convention seperated by underscores in Python. eg: `shoe_size` not `ShoeSize`